# AndroidX GridLayout: incorrect layout when cell content changes

Tags: android, androidx, android-gridlayout

I am using an [AndroidX GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/gridlayout/widget/GridLayout) to display a 2x2 grid of content using the following XML layout:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/outline"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:rowCount="2"
    app:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:iconSize="40dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:iconSize="40dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:iconSize="40dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center"
        app:iconSize="40dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

This is what it looks like when `@string/button_text` is `"button"`:

[image]

But when I increase the length of this string just a little, to `"my button"`, the grid layout suddenly jumps to this:

[image]

I can understand how the content within a grid cell might be truncated or wrapped if too big, but I can't understand why the layout suddenly switches so that the second column is lost entirely.

I can solve this by putting an `android:maxWidth` on each `MaterialButton`, for example `170dp`, but this isn't ideal because it isn't very responsive and won't make use of more available width on larger screen sizes.  And part of the problem is that the length of this string will change depending on which language is being used, so for some longer translations we really may need the extra width (if available).

So I'd rather not put a fixed arbitrary maximum on the button width, and instead just wrap the text within the button (ugly but less ugly than the above).  Or better still, it would be great if the `GridLayout` could automatically switch from 2x2 to 4x1 if any of the cell content is too big to fit.

So what is the correct way of preventing the grid layout jumping horribly like this, and instead just wrapping the text within the grid cell (button)... or switching grid layout to 4x1?

I've put the sample app used for the above code and screenshot [here](https://bitbucket.org/drmrbrewer/gridlayoutdemo/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is not moving to the next row, it just trying to take as width as possible because of using

```
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
```

so you have two possible solutions
first is to remove weight and gravity

```
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="center"
```

or make each column take half of gridlayout by adding width 0dp

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Also if you want TextView to wrap its content and not fill parent as long as it doesn't need to, you will wrap it in another ViewGroup, FrameLayout is suitable for this, this thing is related to TextView not GridLayout

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_textA"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:iconSize="40dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Removing `app:layout_gravity="center"` isn't desirable because I need the content of each cell to be centred within the column.  And adding `android:layout_width="0dp"` just results in a completely empty `GridLayout`.  Furthermore, if the button text translation is a bit long in a particular language, I need the button text to wrap onto two lines (or font size to reduce, or something)... rather than just push the buttons partially out of the `GridLayout` (hidden).

Comment: please check this image and tell me if it's required behavior  https://ibb.co/x237h0D

Comment: You'll see that I've added an alternative in my demo app that is based on a `LinearLayout` (the lower button layout in your image), and that's really what I'm aiming at... i.e. I have achieved what I want, but not using a `GridLayout` but a `LinearLayout`.  I'd still be interested to hear how it should be done with `GridLayout` though.  I don't want each button to fill the entire half-width, but only as wide as needed for the button content (but still fitting withing the grid)... i.e. like my `LinearLayout` solution at the bottom of your image.

Comment: See my updated answer,please

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like the fix to wrap the `MaterialButton` in a `FrameLayout` is actually exactly the same as what I used in the `LinearLayout` alternative in my updated demo app!  :-)  so yes it makes sense now.  And, I think that my `LinearLayout` alternative is better because there is one less dependency, and it ends up looking exactly the same as when using a `GridLayout`... but I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Thanks, If you will have 4 TextView only, it won't make difference but in  case of many TextView, it's preferred to use less LinearLayout and use one GridLayout